# Encapsulation of a VHDL module in Ise XiliniX

Tags: module, vhdl, encapsulation, xilinx

I have a vhdl module called 'inner_module', with some input and output ports, e.g.

```
entity inner_module is 
port (input1, input2 : in std_logic;
      output1, output2 : out std_logic);
end inner_module;
```

and I want to include (encapsulate?) it in another module, called 'outer_module', that is a sort of interface to 'inner_module', such that I don't have to deal with all its details.
Suppose that 'outer_module' has input and output ports, as in

```
entity outer_module is 
port(outer_input1: in std_logic;
   outer_output1: out std_logic);
end outer_module;
```

which are elaborated and appropriately feed to inner_module with the architecture part of outer_module. Same for the inner outputs, which are elaborated in order to evaluate outer_output1.

Let's say that signals input1 and output1 are meant to drive an external evm, e.g. a dac evm, that is connected to my main EVM (virtex 6).

After checking syntax, synthetizing, ... I have to associate the ports to the pin (with I/O pin planning), but the only port that can be associated are the ones from the top module, and I don't have access to signal input1 and output1.

I can add input1 and output1 in the entity declaration of outer_module, but I'd like to "hide" the fact that I use these signals in order to drive the dac evm (it could be a lot of signals), and simply have the interface with the previous entity declaration for outer_module. I'd like to associated the signals input1 and output1 to the correct pins but without doing this "from the top module".

Is it possible? Any ideas or references on how to do that? Or do I always have to include all the signals to be associated to pins in the top module?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a possible solution to this, but I don't think it is a good idea. I think what you are trying to avoid something that you should not. By not passing the "hidden" I/O from your lower level block through the higher level block, you are essentially asking for a global signal/port that you can access from anywhere. There is not a physical reason why you should not be able to do this (i.e. you should be able to connect any signal in your design to an FPGA pin), but it is not how someone would expect your VHDL design to work. "No one" likes "global signals" or variables, because you lose the ability to trace where they came from and where they go.

When you look at your I/O of your top level design, you should be thinking of the I/O as the pins of your target device. Anything that talks with the outside world in your design needs to have a input or output in your top level design.

It is not uncommon for top level designs to be very large for this reason - there are typically lots of interconnect. SDRAM interfaces can quickly blow up the number of signals you have in your top level. Here are some things that you can try to reduce the noise and clutter:

- Utilize records to group signals of similar purpose/function when connecting between internal blocks. In your design, the `inner_module` could have an output port, which has a record type, that contains all the signals that you need to output to your DAC EVM in the top level. I would avoid using records in the port map of your top level design. This may cause confusion with the tools, but this could also be my superstition.
- Utilize vectors, arrays (or arrays of arrays) in order to manage multi-dimensional data and/or busses. This can greatly reduce clutter. Instead of having `bit0`, `bit1`, `bit2`, you can have a signal (a vector) called `bits` and all the elements of the signal will be treated in the same way.
- Put modules that talk to the physical/external (i.e. a SDRAM interface) in the top level of your design (or one level down), instead of inside the block that needs to use the interface. This avoids needing to bring the external interface signals through (potentially) many layers of modules to get to where your interface is instanciated.
- Utilize a good VHDL editor (I like emacs with vhdlmode) which can greatly reduce the number of copy/paste errors you run into by being able to copy an entity (port map) and paste it as an instanciation, as a list of signals, as a component, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still think that the possibility to connect "hidden" signals to pin could help to write more readable codes. I think that it is the same of hiding the actual implementation of a module. Probabibly, as a beginner, I just have to get use to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use record types for your top level ports. Declare the records in a package that can be used at both ends of the connection (e.g. in the FPGA and the simulation model for your DAC).

You can hide the details of the actual signals in the record; if you need to update the record, the top level design needs no changes.

As a port can have only one direction (mode, either in, out or inout) it is common to use a pair of records, one containing all the input signals, another for the outputs.

At the outermost level you may need some experimentation to get the tools (UCF files since you mention Xilinx) to correctly connect FPGA pins to record compponents...